# API call is not finished in time so field is empty Ionic 2

Tags: api, asynchronous, typescript, ionic2

I'm stuck on a bit of code here. I think the problem is that the API call isn't finished in time to get the address. I tried working with promises but I couldn't figure it out. Is there maybe a way to return the address in the getInfo function? Here are the 2 bits of code that I'm stuck with.

this is in the typescript of my page.

```
    getLocation(){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(res => {
        this.geoService.getInfo(res.coords.latitude.toFixed(6),res.coords.longitude.toFixed(6));
        this.general= this.formBuilder.group({
            customerId: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'), Validators.minLength(7), Validators.maxLength(7)])],
            sin: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            name: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')])],
            tel: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[+0-9]*')])],
            email: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9]*[@][a-zA-Z]*[.][a-zA-Z]*')])],
            location: [this.geoService.getAddress()]
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

this is the typescript of my geoService provider

```
getInfo(lat,lng){
this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'&key=AIzaSyB0ApNB_yRcYkEwaOAGI3cUckJqOokopjc')
    .map(res=> res.json()).subscribe(data=>{address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
    console.log(address);
});
}
getAddress(): string{
    console.log(address)
    return address;

}
```

Comment: you should subscribe in the component...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe in the component and set the control in subscribe:

```
 getLocation(){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(res => {
        this.general= this.formBuilder.group({
            customerId: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'), Validators.minLength(7), Validators.maxLength(7)])],
            sin: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            name: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')])],
            tel: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[+0-9]*')])],
            email: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9]*[@][a-zA-Z]*[.][a-zA-Z]*')])],
            location: ['']
        });
        this.geoService.getInfo(res.coords.latitude.toFixed(6),res.coords.longitude.toFixed(6)).subscribe(data=>{
this.general.controls['location'].setValue(data.results[0].formatted_address)
 });

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```

In the Service return mapped data:

```
getInfo(lat,lng){
return this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lng+'&key=AIzaSyB0ApNB_yRcYkEwaOAGI3cUckJqOokopjc')
    .map(res=> res.json())
});
```

This way you are sure your form is set with the data *when request is returned*.

Comment: When I try that I get an "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'." error.

Comment: check the `getInfo` did you add return ?